# Ordering colors on colored bar for dendrogram in R

Tags: r, colors, dendextend

The vignette for the R package dendextend (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dendextend/vignettes/dendextend.html) gives an example of using the colored_bars function with cutreeDynamic from package dynamicTreeCut as follows:

```
# let's get the clusters
library(dynamicTreeCut)
data(iris)
x  <- iris[,-5] %>% as.matrix
hc <- x %>% dist %>% hclust
dend <- hc %>% as.dendrogram 

# Find special clusters:
clusters <- cutreeDynamic(hc, distM = as.matrix(dist(x)), method = "tree")
# we need to sort them to the order of the dendrogram:
clusters <- clusters[order.dendrogram(dend)]
clusters_numbers <- unique(clusters) - (0 %in% clusters)
n_clusters <- length(clusters_numbers)

library(colorspace)
cols <- rainbow_hcl(n_clusters)
true_species_cols <- rainbow_hcl(3)[as.numeric(iris[,][order.dendrogram(dend),5])]
dend2 <- dend %>% 
         branches_attr_by_clusters(clusters, values = cols) %>% 
         color_labels(col =   true_species_cols)
plot(dend2)
clusters <- factor(clusters)
levels(clusters)[-1]  <- cols[-5][c(1,4,2,3)] 
   # Get the clusters to have proper colors.
   # fix the order of the colors to match the branches.

colored_bars(clusters, dend, sort_by_labels_order = FALSE)
```

The following line reorders the colors to match the branches:

```
levels(clusters)[-1]  <- cols[-5][c(1,4,2,3)]
```

I wish to apply this method to my own data which has many more clusters, but I am unclear on how the revised ordering of the colors was determined. This example uses a custom ordering for the iris data. Can anyone explain how this order was determined and is there a way to automate this?

Answer (score 0):

Just for starters, your example code above from the `data(iris)`was missing two necessary packages, `library(dplyr)` to be able to use the pipe command `%>%` and `library(dendextend)` for the label colors, from `color_lables()`

In order to answer your question, solution can be found in the `levels(clusters)[-1]  <- cols[-5][c(1,4,3,2)]` section of code.  As you mention, this is custom to this specific dataset, but I am unaware of why the authors picked this specific order.  If you do not set the order, and want R to automatically do it, than in the `colored_bars()` command, the `sort_by_labels_order=TRUE` must be set.  Here, it is set to FALSE since the authors use a custom order.

If it is set to TRUE, than I cite directly from R "the colors vector/matrix should be provided in the order of the original data order (and it will be re-ordered automatically to the order of the dendrogram)".  For more information, see `?colored_bars()`

This will show you the difference betweeen the two parameters, when set to FALSE or TRUE.

```
# let's get the clusters
library(dynamicTreeCut)
library(dplyr)
data(iris)
x  <- iris[,-5] %>% as.matrix
hc <- x %>% dist %>% hclust
dend <- hc %>% as.dendrogram 

# Find special clusters:
clusters <- cutreeDynamic(hc, distM = as.matrix(dist(x)), method = "tree")
# we need to sort them to the order of the dendrogram:
clusters <- clusters[order.dendrogram(dend)]
clusters_numbers <- unique(clusters) - (0 %in% clusters)
n_clusters <- length(clusters_numbers)

library(colorspace)
library(dendextend)
cols <- rainbow_hcl(n_clusters)
true_species_cols <- rainbow_hcl(3)[as.numeric(iris[,][order.dendrogram(dend),5])]
dend2 <- dend %>% 
  branches_attr_by_clusters(clusters, values = cols) %>% 
  color_labels(col =   true_species_cols)
clusters <- factor(clusters)
levels(clusters)[-1]  <- cols[-5][c(1,4,2,3)] 
plot(dend2);colored_bars(clusters, dend, sort_by_labels_order = FALSE)

# here R automatically assigned the colors
plot(dend2);colored_bars(clusters, dend, sort_by_labels_order = TRUE)
```

Comment: Simply setting sort_by_labels_order to TRUE does not give the same result as achieved by the original code. The original code shows the colored bars in large contiguous blocks, which line up with the colors of the branches of the dendrogram. Setting sort_by_labels_order to TRUE shows the colored bars in the original order of the dendrogram leaves, and therefore broken into many small chunks that do not line up with the colors of the dendrogram branches. That is why the authors have not used that method.